# Cannot display : display alert

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display , display alert when I click on "OnLogOut" but is it not woring and I cannot see why

```
 <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"  BackgroundColor="White"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Orientation="Vertical"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="30" Padding="0,0,0,0">

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <!--Le text est dans la classe-->
                                <Label  x:Name="myemail"   Text=""  TextColor="#36688D" Font="Bold,Italic,20" />
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                     TextColor="#36688D"
                                     FontSize="15"
                                     Text="Log Out"  x:Name="mylogout">     
                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnLogOut"  />
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
```

Here is my c# code:

```
 public async void OnLogOut(object sender, EventArgs args)


            {
       Console.WriteLine("Log out is tapped");
                await DisplayAlert("Email", "Your email please", "✔");
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: How is `OnLogout` called?

Comment: It is an event supposedly...

Comment: @DavidG  when you tappe the label "Log Out"

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?  Does the alert not display or is there an error?

Comment: The alert does not display

Comment: is OnLogout getting called?  Have you checked for exceptions or console log messages?

Comment: yes on the console I have the output "Log out is tapped"

Comment: And these two lines are the only lines in the `OnLogout` method? Nothing comes after it?

Comment: @DavidG yes nothing come after it

Comment: @Jason  yes on the console I have the output "Log out is tapped"

Comment: have you tried add Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread like this: Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => { await DisplayAlert("Email", "Your email please", "✔")});

Comment: still not working @EduardoSilva

Comment: Your code provided worked for me. Try `await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Email", "Your email please", "✔");`

Comment: The code you provided works and the AlertDialog can be displayed. Maybe there are some XAML elements that are on top of your stackLayout and prevent button to be clicked. Comment out your rest XAML and try again to see if your Dialog works.